# Problem with building/compiling a driver for Edimax wireless adapter EW-7822UAC in Kubuntu 13.10 64-bit

Tags: wireless, drivers, usb-modem

I have a USB wireless adapter EW-7822UAC from Edimax, and I used to be able to build/compile a Linux driver from the source that the vendor provided just by installing build-essential package on a fresh installation of Ubuntu, even without updating the system.

Now, I have installed Kubuntu 13.10 64-bit, and when I try to build the driver, I get a bunch of repeated errors and warnings and eventually the build process fails.

The kernel is `3.11.0-12-generic` and I didn't need to install anything other than build-essential in (K)ubuntu 12.04.

The following are the block of repeated warning and error that I got after I invoked make command:

```
/home/xxx/build/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux_v4.2.2_7502.20130517/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:601:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
entry = create_proc_read_entry("bw_mode", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
      ^
/home/xxx/build/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux_v4.2.2_7502.20130517/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:607:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
entry->write_proc = proc_set_bw_mode;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, but please go easy on the jargon. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your super quick replay! The link to the driver source is the following:  http://www.edimax.com/images/Image/Driver_Utility/Wireless/NIC/EW-7822UAC/EW-7822UAC_linux_v4.2.2_7502.20130517.tar.gz

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please check here: https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux On the right hand side, click 'Download ZIP.' Assuming downloads go to your Downloads folder, open the folder, right-click the zip file and select 'Extract Here.' Open a terminal and do:

```
cd Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8812au
```

It 'makes' with a couple of warnings on my 13.10 system, but no errors. I can test no further since I haven't the device. This is a rather new device and we'll be very interested in your report.

Whenever a later kernel version, also known as linux image is installed by Update Manager, after you reboot, you will need to re-compile the driver:

```
cd Downloads/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8812au
```

Comment: The only module it builds is 8812au: "Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /home/chili/8812/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/8812au.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/chili/8812/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/8812au.ko"

Comment: Wow! It worked like a charm! I didn't even have to run the last command, but just unplugged and plugged the adapter in. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Great news. This is a pretty new device and you will have helped many searchers.

Comment: @chili555 I'm getting a `could not insert 8812au invalid argument` error, any guidance?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Please start your own new question and I'll be happy to help.

Comment: Think I figured it out.  It's a result of trying to add the driver to dkms.  Thanks.