# Netgear A6100 wifi usb mini adapter

Tags: 16.04, netgear

I've tried using these instructions: [Problem with building/compiling a driver for Edimax wireless adapter EW-7822UAC in Kubuntu 13.10 64-bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368015/problem-with-building-compiling-a-driver-for-edimax-wireless-adapter-ew-7822uac)

But I get this message in the terminal:

modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8812au': Required key not available

Any suggestions?

Geir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is due to **Secure Boot** option being enabled in your motherboard's BIOS settings. You'll need to disable it to have the driver installed.

I think you might be one of the victims of dual-booting a version of Windows and Ubuntu (like myself).  I've not seen any cases where disabling Secure Boot has caused trouble in Windows so go ahead and see if it works. :)

Comment: If this answer works for you, choose it as the best answer by checking the tick mark to the left for future uses.